# Unexpected "(" at this time

Tags: batch-file

What am I missing? Banging my head against a wall here and I know it's something simple. Been up for hours straight working on this WannaCry nightmare so I'm sure it's a typo somewhere..

```
@echo OFF

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
set VALUE_NAME=SMB1

FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B
    set ValueValue=%%C
)

if defined ValueName (
    if %ValueValue% == 0x0 ( 
    @echo SMB1_Result=FIXED 
    ) else ( 
    @echo SMB1_Result=OTHER 
    )
) else ( 
    @echo SMB1_Result=NOT_FOUND 
)

pause
```

Comment: Try `if "%ValueValue%" == "0x0" (`

Comment: Try changing `if defined ValueName` to `if defined ValueValue` and then replace `if %ValueValue% == 0x0` with `If %ValueValue% Equ 0` although you should really have already ensured that `ValueValue` didn't already exist by including `set "ValueValue="` before the `for` loop.